# Realm doesn't load libwrappers.so

Tags: xamarin.android, realm

I try to use Realm database(version 0.74.1) in Xamarin.Android project. When I do build all is ok, but when I try to run project i get error

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Error executing task BuildApk: /{SolutionPath} /packages/Realm.0.74.1/lib/MonoAndroid44/arm64-v8a/libwrappers.so.

what I can do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The APK is not built during the default build phase so you only get verification that libraries are in the right place when you run the debugger, or explicitly build an APK.

Can you check if the `libwrappers.so` file is actually in that location in the `packages` directory? It should have been put there by NuGet.

Also, is there just one Android target in the solution or have you created a PCL and Android target. The NuGet needs installing into both.